# How can we cache a formatted data in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-query

I am new to `react-query` and appreciate the way it caches the `api response`. I am just curious , is there an out-of-the-box way to cache a formatted version (more suitable to frontend) of  `api response` than the response itself?
We use to do that in `react-redux` where we can cache something in `store` in a specific format so that interested react components can read that formatted value.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return whatever promise you want from the `queryFn` - it doesn't have to be the exact api response. Transformations can be done, too.

I've done an extensive write-up on this topic: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations